# c++ matrix initialization using std::vector

Tags: c++, matrix, c++14

I am attempting to initialize a matrix that is realized as a vector of vector of doubles. I.e.,

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> A {std::vector<double> {}}; 
std::vector<std::vector<double>>::iterator it = A.begin();
```

My idea is to use a pointer to each "row", access the "push_back" through this pointer to fill up my rows. To make new rows, I simply use:

```
A.push_back(std::vector<double> {});
```

And then have my pointer point to the next row by simply:

```
it++;
```

And then fill my next row. 
The code complies just fine (I am using C++14 standard). However when I run it, I get this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix)
{
  typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> row;
  typedef std::vector<double> col;
  for(row::iterator it = matrix.begin();it!=matrix.end();it++)
  {
    for(col::iterator ti = it->begin();ti!=it->end();ti++)
    {
      std::cout << *ti << ' ';
    }
    std::cout  << '\n';
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> A {std::vector<double> {}};
  std::vector<std::vector<double>>::iterator it = A.begin();
  it->push_back(1);
  it->push_back(2);
  it->push_back(3);
  A.push_back(std::vector<double> {});
  it++;
  it->push_back(4);
  it->push_back(5);
  it->push_back(6);
  print(A);
  return 0;
}
```

(You may it for granted that the print function works as intended without errors, during compiling or runtime).

Any inputs will be helpful. 
Cheers

Comment: Push-back invalidates iterators.  You have to use vector::back().push_back(...)

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` is not the right type for a matrix anyway. Even if we ignore the performance implications, a matrix is a *rectangular* block of stuff and not a list of lists. The data structure should reflect that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I agree with you. However, I am novice C++ programmer with no background to data structures and algorithms.

Comment: Sure, that's why I'm telling you. This was not meant to be a personal attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `vector<>` iterators may be invalidated by the call to `push_back()`.

```
A.push_back(std::vector<double> {});
//it may be invalid at this point because of new allocation in the vector
it++;
```

When you call `push_back()`, the `vector` will likely have to reallocate memory in order to accommodate the new data. This will cause the previous iterators to no longer point to a correct location in memory, and using them further will result in undefined behavior.

If you call `A.begin()` after the `push_back()` in order to reassign your iterator and then do the increment, then the code works as expected for me. Such as:

```
A.push_back(std::vector<double> {});
it = A.begin();
it++;
```

EDIT

If you would like to partially avoid the reassignment of the iterator to the beginning, you could use this:

```
it++;
it = A.insert(it,std::vector<double>{});
```

This will add a new `vector<double>` right before where `it` is pointing (in this case, just before the end of the current `vector`). This will then return an iterator stored in `it` that will point to the `vector` you just inserted, so you can use the result of the code as is.

Comment: Is there a way around having to reassign the iterator. You see, this is part of a bigger picture to create my 'matrix' class. I just tried using it = A.end() , without having to increment (right?). But now I have encountered a segfault

Comment: @NageshEranki Don't use `it = A.end()`. Use `it = A.back();`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Correct, however vector::back is not returning an iterator, but is the right way to do it. (see my answer)

Comment: @NageshEranki I updated my answer to give a potential solution. kiloalphaindia provides another answer that should work in your specific case, but the iterator solution would generalize better to cases where you would like to insert/remove rows within the matrix instead of just the end

Answer (score 0):

As you want to append data to your outer vector you can also do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> A {std::vector<double> {}};
A.back().push_back(1);
A.back().push_back(2);
A.back().push_back(3);
A.push_back(std::vector<double> {});
A.back().push_back(4);
A.back().push_back(5);
A.back().push_back(6);
print(A);
```

[the author of the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257721/7637816) is of cause correct what concerns the invalidation of the iterator

For an implemantation of Matrix functions you may also use [Eigen Template Libaray](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)